# UITapGestureRecognizer not updating UIView until completion

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am running swift 4 on Xcode 9.4.1.  My program uses a UITapGestureRecognizer for single taps with the code below:

```
    let screenTapOnce = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(singleTapGesture))
    screenTapOnce.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(screenTapOnce)
```

The singletap function is:

```
    @objc func singleTapGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
```

This function has a lot of code since it is the main way to interface with the game.  My problem is that any change this function makes to the UIView, (even starting a simple activity indicator) does not display until after the singleTapGesture function completes.  This is a problem as I would like to show some progress during a special screen update that take 2 seconds to calculate.

Any help to understand how to force an UIView update or even understand why UITapGestureRecognizer seems to block any updates  would be appreciated.

Comment: But _show_ us the code.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that any change this function makes to the UIView, (even starting a simple activity indicator) does not display until after the singleTapGesture function completes.

That is how iOS works. Drawing takes place on the CATransaction commit, which starts when *all* your code has run to completion.

> This is a problem as I would like to show some progress during a special screen update that take 2 seconds to calculate

Then you need to get off the main thread and onto a background thread. If you take two seconds to calculate something on the main thread, the Watchdog process will kill your app dead before the user's very eyes. There are straightforward ways to display an indication of progress (on the main thread) while you are doing time-consuming work (on a background thread).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Moving the function to a background thread allowed the UIView to be updated.  The game is calculating all the squares a user can reach.  Each square is a new calculation.  This change gives the user nice incremental information when a particularly large selection field is needed.  I think this solves my problem.  I did not show all the code in the function since it is very large.  Thanks for the great help.